# Is it a good practice to have POJO settings class as a bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a simple POJO class with few fields. This POJO serves the role of settings and it is passed to one method which actually executes some logic. Fields from this POJO are taken from the app.properties and they will not change.
What is a better pratice?

1. Create this POJO every time we want to call the method which needs it.
2. Make it a singleton bean, create it once and then autowire it?

Comment: It sounds like you may be confusing DTO with "POJO" generally, and in particular you should read about `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: YES, SORRY, I MEANT POJO

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot provides [the `@ConfigurationProperties` mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) specifically to automate this for you. In general, it's best to avoid direct dependencies on `MyServiceProperties` and to do the injection in an `@Bean` method, but the `MyServiceProperties` instance is available as a context bean.

Comment: It's what most of the internal Spring Boot components use, too: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html